# ArcPy - Force layers to inherit their ColorMap when visualized

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, colormap

I have a large set of GeoTiff's which after manipulating I apply a colormap to the ones I want to visualize with:

```
arcpy.AddColormap_management(raster, "", color_map)
```

I then add them to my MapDocument with:

```
mapping.AddLayer(df,layer, "BOTTOM")
```

But they do not automatically use the Color Map Symbology that I had designated but instead use a Stretched Symbology. I want to be able to have the layer use its color map by default either after it is added or before, so that either before I add it or after it's added I can change it to visualize this.

Alternatively, some way to set the imported layer to Apply Unique Values, as this automatically generates the color map manually in the TOC and removes the colors which don't have the values in the color map.

How can this be done? Below is an example of what the symbology should look like "raster01" and what I don't want it to look like (i.e. what it looks like when I import it with AddLayer) "raster02".

[image]

Comment: Is this not working for you? https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-color-map-clr-file.htm